# $(\cos 2x + \cos x -1)/(\cos 2x) > 2$ for $x \in <0,\pi>$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Have a trig problem here but it's not coming out right and would appreciate if someone could point out where I've gone wrong.

$$\require{Cancel}\frac{\cos2x + \cos x -1}{\cos 2x} > 2 \\ x \in <0,\pi>$$
First pull out $1$:
$$1 + \frac{\cos x-1}{\cos 2x} >2 
\\\\\text {Assume} \\\cos 2x\neq0$$
Next use identity and move $2$ over:
$$1 + \frac{\cos x -1}{2\cos^2x -1} -2 >0$$
Use $t$ instead:
$$\frac{t -1}{2t^2 -1} -1 >0 \\\ \cos x = t$$
Use expansion formula:
$$\frac{t -1}{2(t-1)(t+1)} -1 >0 \\\ \cos x = t$$
Multply both sides to remove fraction:
$$-1 - 2t - 2 > 0$$
Then we have:
$$\cos x<\frac32$$

Not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: $2t^2-1\not=2(t-1)(t+1)$.

Comment: use a backslash before writing any function in MathJax, I mean to say write `\cos x` instead of `cos x`. and what normal human said, try to post a title without MathJax, else,  it will be hard to find this question later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$$\frac{\cos(2x)+\cos(x)-1}{\cos(2x)}>2\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\left(\cos(2x)+\cos(x)-1\right)\sec(2x)>2\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(\cos(x)-1)\sec(2x)+1>2\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(\cos(x)-1)\sec(2x)>1$$

So know we can find the four possible solutions for the 'overall' problem:

$$2\pi n-\frac{3\pi}{4}<x<\frac{1}{2}(4\pi n-\pi)$$
$$2\pi n+\frac{\pi}{4}<x<\frac{1}{3}(6\pi n+\pi)$$
$$\frac{1}{3}(6\pi n-\pi)<x<2\pi n-\frac{\pi}{4}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}(4\pi n+\pi)<x<2\pi n+\frac{3\pi}{4}$$

With $n\in\mathbb{Z}$